# JFrame Screen Replacing Questions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, refresh

The problem that I am having is when I try to replace the main screen with a second one and it deletes the old one but is stuck placing in the new one. If I maximize the screen I can see the new Panels. Another question I had was how to take up spaces in a grid layout without using all of the filler jpanels that I have to do. The code is below:

```
package home.personalprojects.jordan.ArrayGame;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GuiMain extends JFrame
{

private JButton Inventory, Store, Up, Down, Left, Right, Move, GameInfo, Back = new JButton("Back");
private JLabel pstats, roominfo;
private JPanel Filler1,Filler2,Filler3,Filler4,Filler5,Filler6,Filler7,Filler8,Filler9,Filler10,Filler11;
private JPanel Controls, Main = new JPanel(), BackPanel;

PlayerTraits pt = new PlayerTraits();
Rooms rm = new Rooms();

public GuiMain(){
    super("Dungeon Crawler v 0.0.1 Created By: Jordan Savage");
    Main.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    //mainbuttons
    Inventory = new JButton("Inventory");
    Inventory.setToolTipText("Gives you access to all of your items and lets      you manage them");

    Store = new JButton("Store");
    Store.setToolTipText("The marketplace where you can buy and sell items such as swords and armor");

    Move = new JButton("Move");
    Move.setToolTipText("Choose where you want to move next");

    GameInfo = new JButton("Game Information and Settings");
    GameInfo.setToolTipText("All the info for the game including instructions, version info, and settings");

    //main labels
    pstats = new JLabel(pt.name + ": " + pt.gold + " Gold, " + pt.health + " Health, and Level is " + pt.lvl);
    roominfo = new JLabel("You are at: (" + pt.x + "," + pt.y + ") In room: " + rm.name);

    //fillers for grid layout
    Filler1 = new JPanel();Filler2 = new JPanel();Filler3 = new JPanel();Filler4 = new JPanel();Filler5 = new JPanel();Filler6 = new JPanel();Filler7 = new JPanel();Filler7 = new JPanel();Filler8 = new JPanel();Filler9 = new JPanel();Filler10 = new JPanel();Filler11 = new JPanel();  

    //action listeners
    Move.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ControlScheme();
            BackToMain();
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(Controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            getContentPane().add(BackPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            getContentPane().doLayout();
            update(getGraphics());
        }
    });

    Back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(Main);
            getContentPane().doLayout();
            update(getGraphics());
        }
    });

    Main.add(Inventory);
    Main.add(Filler1);
    Main.add(Store);
    Main.add(Filler2);
    Main.add(pstats);
    Main.add(Filler3);
    Main.add(Filler4);
    Main.add(roominfo);
    Main.add(Filler5);
    Main.add(Move);
    Main.add(Filler6);
    Main.add(GameInfo);
    add(Main);
}

public void BackToMain(){
    BackPanel = new JPanel();
    BackPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    BackPanel.add(Back);
}


public void ControlScheme(){
    Up = new JButton("Up");
    Down = new JButton("Down");
    Left = new JButton("Left");
    Right = new JButton("Right");

    Controls = new JPanel();
    Controls.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    Controls.add(Filler7);
    Controls.add(Up);
    Controls.add(Filler8);
    Controls.add(Left);
    Controls.add(Filler9);
    Controls.add(Right);
    Controls.add(Filler10);
    Controls.add(Down);
    Controls.add(Filler11);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    GuiMain gm = new GuiMain();
    gm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gm.setSize(800, 600);
    gm.setVisible(true);
    gm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

}
```

Any Help Is Appreciated :)

Comment: Please try to adapt your coding style to the [java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java) otherwise you will confuse us and it will be harder to know what is a class and what is a variable name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just changed them to the right casing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be to call `revalidate` on the frame.

The better answer would be to use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which was designed to do exactly what you are trying to do...

As to your second question, it can't be done with `GridLayout`, in fact, you might find it difficult to achieve even with `GridBagLayout` which gives you control over the placement of components within the virtual grid.

What you might be able to do, is use the fill the grid with empty panels, keeping them in some kind of matrix lookup (ie `getComponentAt(gridx, gridy)`) and use these to place your components onto instead.

So, for example.  If you wanted to place a panel at grid `2x3`, you would simply look at the panel at that grid location and place your components onto it.

ps- While I think about, you might also need `repaint` after `revalidate` if `revalidate` along doesn't work...

Comment: Thank You! For now I just called revalidate but I will definatly try out a CardLayout. Revalidate alone worked.